# Excel: Why does my line chart look like a column chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel 2019, I want to create a line chart, but the series have vertical bars:

[image]

Under chart elements, error bars, trendline, and up/down bars are all turned off:

[image]

Under Format Data Series > Fill & Line > Line, Line is set to Automatic:

[image]

If I change that to Solid line, it just changes the color of the vertical bars.

Under Format Data Series > Fill & Line > Marker, Marker Options is None, Fill is No Fill, and Border is No Line:

[image]

Under Format Data Series > Effects, all effects appear to be turned off:

[image]

How do I get my line chart to be an actual line chart instead of a column chart?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's what I figured out.

The data have a lot of cells in which the value is `""`. Now, Excel has as default behavior that empty cells are charted as gaps in the data, which is what I want. (In Excel 2019, this behavior is set by "Chart > Select Data > Hidden and Empty Cells > Show empty cells as > Gaps".) However, the tricky bit is that a cell containing `""` is not empty. An empty cell is one that has nothing in it, not even a formula that evaluates to `""`. So my chart was interpreting those `""`s as zeros and the vertical bars were caused by the the line of the chart connecting the nonzero values with the zero values.

Since my data are all generated by formulas, how was I to get gaps in the line instead of vertical bars? The answer is another setting under "Chart > Select Data > Hidden and Empty Cells", which is "Show #N/A as an empty cell". This is checked by default. With that, if I modify my formulas so that instead of outputting `""`, they call the function `NA()`, which generates `#N/A`, then I get the gaps I need.

This is weird because I've always considered it best practice to eliminate errors. Usually I do that by using `IfError()` to replace the error with `""`. But here I have to do the opposite. The resulting data worksheet is ugly because it's full of `#N/A` errors. But the chart is the proper line style with gaps instead of looking like a column chart.